# HTML and CSS are fine, but once I add Jquery, it does not have the toggle effect? how can I fix it?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I just want to have the toggle to work: when I click on the "div", I hope that the div can toggle between "show-description", and since the "show-description" has a height and opacity setting, the div can appear and disappear. But currently, the jquery does not work, I cannot click the div(my cursor will not change from an arrow to a pointer that indicates it is clickable.)

I attached my code(HTML, css and js) in this thread as texts and images.They are three separate files as of right now.I am new to coding so I hope someone can help me.

```js
$("div").on("click", function(){  
   $(this).toggleClass("show-description"); });
```

```css
div {
height: 300px;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
margin: 10px;}


p {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
    padding: 10px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.4));
    padding: 10px;

    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 28px;
    border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 30px;
}

small {
    opacity: 0;
}

.show-description p{
    height: 150px;
}

.show-description small{
    opacity: 1;
}

.price {
    float: right;
}


.first {
background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/flat-lay-bowls-with-powder_23-2148583721.jpg");
border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
}

.second {
background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/delicious-beef-burgers-wooden-board_23-2148290634.jpg");  
border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
}

.last {
background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/chocolate-cake-with-chocolate-sprinkles_144627-8998.jpg");
border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;}
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="cafe.css">
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Londrina+Shadow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="cafeScript.js"></script>

</head>
<h1>Esha's restaurant</h1>

<div class="first ">

  <p>welsh onion soko <span class="price">$14</span><br />
<small>Mustard sierra leone bologi kale chard beet greens black-eyed pea sorrel amaranth garlic tigernut spring onion summer purslane asparagus lentil. </small></p>
</div>


<div class="second show-description">
  <p>pastrami boudin tongue <span class="price">$22</span><br />

<small>Tri-tip capicola kielbasa salami brisket chicken rump strip steak drumstick. Meatloaf chuck boudin ribeye pork jowl. Andouille bacon jowl meatloaf pork loin prosciutto bresaola.</small></p>
</div>

<div class="last">

  <p>fruitcake marzipan pudding dragee <span class="price">$8</span><br />
<small>Lollipop tart cotton candy jelly-o carrot cake apple pie cupcake. Jelly-o bear claw ice cream candy canes.</small></p>
</div>

<body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please take a moment to read [ask]. There are several tips in that article on getting the most out of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Learn more about [ .toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
Check the [liveFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/2mogezxb/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly fine.
To change the cursor type so that users know it's clickable you will have to set `cursor:pointer` in related CSS style.
**Snippet with `cursor:pointer` added to existing code:**

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("show-description");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .4));
  padding: 10px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .4));
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
}

small {
  opacity: 0;
}

.show-description p {
  height: 150px;
}

.show-description small {
  opacity: 1;
}

.price {
  float: right;
}

.first {
  background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/flat-lay-bowls-with-powder_23-2148583721.jpg");
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
}

.second {
  background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/delicious-beef-burgers-wooden-board_23-2148290634.jpg");
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
}

.last {
  background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/chocolate-cake-with-chocolate-sprinkles_144627-8998.jpg");
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
}

.div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="cafe.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Londrina+Shadow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="cafeScript.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Esha's restaurant</h1>

  <div class="first ">

    <p>welsh onion soko <span class="price">$14</span><br/>
      <small>Mustard sierra leone bologi kale chard beet greens black-eyed pea sorrel amaranth garlic tigernut spring onion summer purslane asparagus lentil. </small></p>
  </div>


  <div class="second show-description">
    <p>pastrami boudin tongue <span class="price">$22</span><br/>

      <small>Tri-tip capicola kielbasa salami brisket chicken rump strip steak drumstick. Meatloaf chuck boudin ribeye pork jowl. Andouille bacon jowl meatloaf pork loin prosciutto bresaola.</small></p>
  </div>

  <div class="last">

    <p>fruitcake marzipan pudding dragee <span class="price">$8</span><br/>
      <small>Lollipop tart cotton candy jelly-o carrot cake apple pie cupcake. Jelly-o bear claw ice cream candy canes.</small></p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery overkill here. You can do the same thing or something similar with vanilla javascript.